# How to get data from database to one select option to another option in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
Category:   <select name="category">
<option>Choose Category</option>
<?php 
include("connect.php");
$select="SELECT * FROM category";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$select) or die (mysqli_error($link));

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    echo "<option value='$row[category]'>".$row['category'];

    }
?>
</select>

<br>
Subcategory:<select name="category">
<?php
include("connect.php");

$category=@$_POST['category'];

if($category=="Friuts")
{
    $select="SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE $category='$category'";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$select) or die (mysqli_error($link));

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    echo "<option value='echo $row[subcategory]'>".$row['subcategory'];

    }
}


?>

</select>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Open" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two tables, table one name category and table two name subcategory, I want two when I choice one item option from table category get data from table subcategory in the select option appear in the image below:

[This image is table category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF8fk.jpg)

[This image is table subcategory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ULy.jpg)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: @AlexHowansky This is my code, how i can fix?

Comment: Maybe read the links I posted?

Comment: Thank you @AlexHowansky I read it and i will tray.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplice what you want you need to:

1. Create a select box that shows the values from the main table, best is to use the category_id as value
2. Check if the form has been submitted (thus `if( isset( $_POST['category'] ) ) {}`. Ifso, run a query on the subcategory table and check for cat_id = $_POST['category']
3. show the results from the second query in a select box.

Or in short:

```
echo "<option value='$row[cat_id]'>".$row['category'];

$select='SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE cat_id="' . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $category ).'"';
```

*NOT tested*
and PLEASE read the websites 'Alex Howansky' provided!

Comment: Using a prepared statement would still be better than escaping the string

Comment: I 100% agree. That's why he should read the links Alex Howansky provided.

Comment: @Sanderbakker how i can use prepare statement?

Comment: @Jeffrey sorry where is the link? how i can find?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I see Alex Howansky but don't find.

Comment: @Talib remember replying with `Thank you AlexHowansky I read it and i will tray.`. Those links i'm talking about